# Логика построения Android-приложения с использованием MVP+Dagger2

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, realm, mvp, dagger2

Пытаюсь добраться до сути и логики построения android-приложения по шаблону MVP, используя при этом Dagger2. И есть некоторое недопонимание в некоторых конкретных реализациях.

В качестве ORM к БД использую Realm:

```
public class RealmHelper  {    
    private Realm realm;
    // методы для работы с БД
}
```

Как правильно инжектить класс `RealmHelper` с помощью Dagger2?

Правильно его инжектить в классы `BaseActivity` и `BaseFragment`, от которых наследуются все экраны или инжектить в каждую отдельную активити, где он в последствии понадобится?

Или же вообще правильно инжектить в класс презентера?
Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что работать с Dagger 2 вы умеете, вопрос в том в каком классе использовать RealmHelper, верно?

Comment: @iamtihonov в целом, да. Но от обширного ответа не откажусь)

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вариант реализации паттерна выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`RealmHelper` в вашем случае должен находиться только внутри `DataManager`, доступа к нему из `Activity`, `Fragment` быть не должно .Если опустить `DataManager` то можно тогда в `Presenter` поместить. Лучше всего если он будет передаваться в качестве параметра конструктора в виде интерфейса класса, например `IRealmHelper` для возможности написания в будущем модульного теста для `DataManager`.

Пример:

```
interface IRealmHelper {
    Data loadData();
}

class RealmHelper implements IRealmHelper  {
    public Data loadData() {
        //реализация
    }
}

interface IDataManager {
    Data loadData();
}

class DataManager implements IDataManager {

    private IRealmHelper realmHelper;

    DataManager(IRealmHelper realmHelper) {
        this.realmHelper = realmHelper;
    }

    public Data loadData() {
        //Дополнительно обычно в этом месте запрос делается асинхронным, если это необходимо, например с помощью `RxAndroid` или `AsyncTask`.
        return realmHelper.loadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, схема это здорово) Но мне бы тогда увидеть код как это реализовать с использвоанием DataManager (ранее я не встречал такую прослойку между презентером и моделью). И как быть с десятком примеров, где DBHelper инжектится в активити?Это в корне неправильно или нежелательно?

Comment: @SergeyK. Вам достаточно кода не связанного с Dagger2? Если нет то это уже будет два вопроса, что не желательно на so

Comment: @iiamtihonov да, будет достаточно. MVP интересует больше

Comment: @SergeyK. На счет примеров где DBHelper инжектиться в Activity, в этом случае это уже не MVP

Comment: да я немного перепутал, инжектят в презентер. Как здесь например: https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/example-realm-mvp-dagger/

Comment: @Поправил ответ. В целом можно и в Presenter, если DataManager не нужен. MVP - это шаблон проектирования, способов его реализации есть много.

Comment: инжектить в каждый презентер? Или можно в BasePresenter, от которого все презентеры наследуются?

Comment: Инжектиться будет каждый конструктор презентера, а передаваться ему уже будет в констуктор IRealmHelper в вашем случае или RealmHelper как уже реализуете. Хотя можете и инжектить RealmHelper. Выбор за вами

Comment: а не будет ли это перегрузкой кода, когда я буду описывать модули для dagger? Если нужно например будет использовать RealmHelper в 15-20 презентерах к примеру.

Comment: @SergeyK. если инжектить RealmHelper. то можете его в BasePresenter как вы и писали